# Using twitter bootstrap 3 with rails using bootstrap-sass gem

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

Right now my bootstrap css version is v2.3.2 with following gem

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2.1'
```

I tried to upgrade it by using following configuration

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', git: 'https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass.git', branch: '3'
```

But after restarting the server and everything the version remained the same

So I tried `bundle exec rake convert`, maybe it could fix the problem

But it kept throwing

```
Don't know how to build task 'convert'
```

So does anyone have any idea how to implement bootstrap v3 into my rails project ??

Answer (score 10):

I had to run this command

```
rake tmp:clear
```

In order to clear the cache from bootstrap v2 files

Answer (score 2):

As per the instructions at rubygems.org, you have to run this command to get the new gem. I assume this is because it is using release candidates.

```
$ gem install bootstrap-sass --pre
```

I don't know how you would do this in the Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap-sass github page is not so clear.
You **don't need** to run the convert task unless you're working or developing the gem itself. 
You just need to follow the [bootstrap-sass rails install guide](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/blob/3/docs/RAILS.md)